# Переопределение свойства объекта в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, ооп

Все-таки мучает меня этот вопрос, может быть кто-то сможет объяснить.

> Yii advanced 2.0.13

Есть модель Categories, у нее есть свойство `content`

> @param string $content

При добавлении в базу $content кодируется в JSON, при изъятии из базы $content декодируется в массив.

Итак в чем собсно смысл:

**Весь код исполняем в методе actionUpdate до загрузки данных в модель**

Изначальные данные

```
print_r($model);
/* вывод выглядит немного не так, потому что это все-таки более крупный объект, но общий смысл такой
Array
(
    [name] => bla
    [content] => Array
        (
            [image] => bla-bla.bla
            [seo-title] => bla-bla
        )

)*/
```

Куски кода ниже выполнялись не подряд вместе разумеется

**1** И так пробуем

```
echo $model->name; // bla
$model->name = 'new_name';
echo $model->name; // new_name
```

**2** Тут все понятно и логично, переназначили $model->name - проблем нет

```
$model->content = 'new_string_content';
echo $model->content; // new_string_content
```

**3** Аналогично, без проблем. Был массивом, стал строкой, данные сохранились

```
$model->content['seo-title'] = 'new_string_seo';
echo $model->content['seo-title']; // bla-bla
```

**4** А вот в этой ситуации перезапись уже не срабатывает и остается то значение, которое было, однако, это можно реализовать если сделать так:

```
$content = $model->content;
$content['seo-title'] = 'new_string_seo';
$model->content = $content;
echo $model->content['seo-title']; // new_string_seo
```

Так работает.

**Объясните, пожалуйста, почему не работает вариант 3?** Под "не работает" я имеею ввиду 0 реакции, нет ошибок, просто остается старое значение

> Код, если нужно:

Лишние методы я удалил, чтобы не мазолили глаза

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{%categories}}".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property integer $status
 * @property integer $sort_order
 * @property integer $parent_id
 * @property string $content
 *
 * @property Categories $parent
 * @property Categories[] $categories
 * @property CategoriesRelationships[] $categoriesRelationships
 * @property CategoriesRelationships[] $categoriesRelationships0
 * @property ProductsToCategories[] $productsToCategories
 */
class Categories extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%categories}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name'], 'required'],
            [['status', 'sort_order'], 'integer'],
            ['content', 'each', 'rule' => ['trim']],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['parent_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Categories::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['parent_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Заголовок',
            'status' => 'Показывать',
            'sort_order' => 'Порядок сортировки',
            'parent_id' => 'Родительская категория',
            'content' => 'Содержание',
        ];
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {

            $this->content = json_encode($this->content, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function afterFind() {
        $this->content = json_decode($this->content, true);
    }




}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\Categories;
use backend\models\CategoriesCRUD;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

/**
 * CategoriesController implements the CRUD actions for Categories model.
 */
class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Updates an existing Categories model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);


            //echo $model->name; // bla
            //$model->name = 'new_name';
            //echo $model->name; // new_name

            //$model->content = 'new_string_content';
            //echo $model->content; // new_string_content

            //$model->content['seo-title'] = 'new_string_seo';
            //echo $model->content['seo-title']; // bla-bla

            $content = $model->content;
            $content['seo-title'] = 'new_string_seo';
            $model->content = $content;
            echo $model->content['seo-title']; // new_string_seo
            die();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Finds the Categories model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Categories the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Categories::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

**Форма**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput() ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'content[meta-title]')->textInput(['maxlength'=>60])->label('Meta-title')->hint('Если строка не заполнена, будет использован шаблонный meta-title') ?>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'content[image]')->fileInput()->label('Изображение') ?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Создать' : 'Обновить', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется **косвенной модификацией перегруженного свойства**.

В PHP есть возможность динамически создавать свойства и методы "на лету" с помощью [методов перегрузки](http://us.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php) `__get`, `__set`... как впрочем на многих языках.

Проблема заключается в том, что ваше свойство - это не "реальное" свойство (ActiveRecord реализует свойства модели с помощью магического `__get` метода как я назвал выше "на лету").

Получается, что вы пытаетесь изменить возвращаемое значение функции. Это примерно тоже самое, что попытка сделать так:

```
function content() {
    return [1 => 1];
}
(content())[1] = 2;
```

"Неприятная неожиданность" (не могу назвать это проблемой) решаема несколькими способами, но то решение, что вы сами нашли в предидущем вашем вопросе самое безобидное:

```
$content = $model->content;
$content['image'] = 'bla-bla-bla';
$model->content = $content;
```